# Code for adding homepage in ReactJS and want to route to a page

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want ReactJS homepage. I already done my login page. But I want to expand my project by adding a login page before login. I'm a beginner in ReactJS. I did my login page. But I doesn't know how to create a homepage with navigation bar including loginpage and to route to login page after running. Please anyone help me to code this project. This is my loginform.js page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
import './LoginForm.css';



class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let {username, password} = this.state;
    let {isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError} = this.props;

    return (
          <div>

         <header>
   <h1>Company Login</h1>
   </header>
      <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <div className="imgcontainer">
    <img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" className="avatar"/>
  </div>

        <div className="form-group-collection">
          <div className="form-group">

            <label>Username/User ID:</label>
            <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({username: e.target.value})} value={username}/>
          </div>


          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} value={password}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />

  </form>
     <footer>Copyright &copy; multihands.com. </footer>
     </div> 
    )
  }






  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
    this.setState({
      username: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
    isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
    loginError: state.loginError
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

This is my reducer.js

```
import logindetls from '../../logindet.json';

const SET_LOGIN_PENDING = 'SET_LOGIN_PENDING';
const SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS';
const SET_LOGIN_ERROR = 'SET_LOGIN_ERROR';

export function login(username, password) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(setLoginPending(true));
    dispatch(setLoginSuccess(false));
    dispatch(setLoginError(null));

    callLoginApi(username, password, error => {
      dispatch(setLoginPending(false));
      if (!error) {
        dispatch(setLoginSuccess(true));
      } else {
        dispatch(setLoginError(error));
      }
    });
  }
}

function setLoginPending(isLoginPending) {
  return {
    type: SET_LOGIN_PENDING,
    isLoginPending
  };
}

function setLoginSuccess(isLoginSuccess) {
  return {
    type: SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    isLoginSuccess
  };
}

function setLoginError(loginError) {
  return {
    type: SET_LOGIN_ERROR,
    loginError
  }
}

function callLoginApi(username, password, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {

    if (username === logindetls.username && password === logindetls.password)
        {
        return alert("Successfully Logged in...");
    } else {
      return alert('Invalid username and password');
    }
  }, 1000);
}


export default function reducer(state = {
  isLoginSuccess: false,
  isLoginPending: false,
  loginError: null
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_LOGIN_PENDING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoginPending: action.isLoginPending
      });

    case SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoginSuccess: action.isLoginSuccess
      });

    case SET_LOGIN_ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loginError: action.loginError
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducer from './reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
export default store;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a routing library to manage your routes rather than doing it manually. I suggest you use React Router which is very flexible and stable routing library for react.

You can learn it by using [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) tutorial, which I found very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple, you need change order of calls.

firts functions and before defined exports.

When you use Slint jlint is very stric for calls methods or fuctions, and you need depends of order for calls.

Comment: Your answer is not quite clear. Could you elaborate?